# How to record login time and make it static

Tags: c#, .net

Let say after I logged into the main window, the login time is recorded and it will show in the child window (e.g I click a specified button and the child window will pop out and display the time). My problem is how to make the recorded login time become static? I used `DateTime dateTime = DateTime.Now`, it did give me the time, but everytime I close the child window and re-open it, the time keeps updating to current time.

Comment: Really depends on where you captured `DateTime.Now`.  It's not clear if you did it in the child windows that is causing it to be invoked every single time.  Ideally, this should reside in the Main windows say when the form is initialized or even in the `Program` class.  First time that thing is fired up, it logged the time as a public variable or public static and just refer to it once it is set and if possible just set it once if it is not the default value or if it is `DateTime?` then compare it to `null` and only set it when it's `null`.

Comment: You may want to create a class with fields like `UserName` and `LogonTime` that capture this information. Create an instance of that class when a user logs on, and store it in a member variable of your main form so that you can reference and pass it around to other forms that need it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample of the `Program` class as mentioned above which you can extend a bit more with Alex' suggestion.  But for simplicity sake I am just assuming you just want to track the Login Timestamp...

```
    static class Program
    {
        private static DateTime? _loginTime;
        private static readonly object PadLock = new object();

        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }

        public static void SetLoginTime()
        {
            if (_loginTime != null) return;

            lock (PadLock)
            {
                if (_loginTime != null) return;
                _loginTime = DateTime.UtcNow;       //Only set this when _loginTime is still null after locking
            }
        }

        public static DateTime? GetLoginTime()
        {
            return _loginTime;
        }
    }
```

In the example above, we will only be setting the login time when it is still `null`, so additional call to the `SetLoginTime` method will do nothing.

Either as party of Main() or when the user click a Login button on the Main form, as the last method call in the Login click event handler, call `Program.SetLoginTime()`.  That will record the time into the static field in `Program` static field.

And in the child form, just set whatever `Label` you use to display the login time to something like: `lblLoginTimestamp.Text = Program.GetLoginTime();`